# How to clone an object created by a factory?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory

I was thinking about this problem and couldn't quite figure out what would be the most logical solution. I'll put forth the scenario of an interface/abstract class Animal, class Fish which inherits from Animal, and factory class AnimalFactory which instantiates Animal objects. I am tasked with cloning an instance of Fish. For reference, by 'clone' I mean using instance A to create a new instance B, where A != B, yet their classes and states are identical.

Now, my question is: how would you clone an instance of Fish? I guess what I'm wondering most here is, do you call the factory to clone it or not? Outlined below are the two most logical solutions I've come up with:

- `public clone() {/* return new fish with the same state */}` in the Fish class.
- `public clone(Animal toClone) {/* return toClone.clone() */}` in the AnimalFactory class, where `clone()` in the Fish class has protected access.

To reiterate my question: how would you clone an object created by a factory?

Comment: The factory needn't be involved since the object can clone itself.

Comment: @jaco0646 Sure, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of using the factory?

Comment: Presumably, the purpose of the factory is to create the original object.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks